# Spring boot, Spring Data JPA with Cassandra | Codec for ZonedDateTime not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have a spring boot application and we use Spring Data JPA for querying to our Cassandra DB. We have a timestamp column and currently we are using the LocalDateTime in java to map to the DB column.

Sample of Entity

```
@Table(value = "user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "userid", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    @CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
    private String userId;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "createddatetime", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    @CassandraType(type = Name.TIMESTAMP)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

When we query the table, sometimes because of the timezone, we are getting different result set. So, instead of LocalDateTime, I want to use the ZonedDateTime for createdDate variable (createddatetime column).

I have added the extra codecs of Cassandra to use the ZonedDateTimeCodec but not sure how to add it to the registry. I wanted to know if there is a way to only add the new codec and still use the spring's way of querying the database without actually having to configure cluster etc. via code.